# Unity 2D jump from circle to circle always facing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to make something similar to Super Mario Galaxy's planet traversal where the player has to jump from planet to planet but the difference here is that the player is orbiting around the player instead of walking on it. I've managed to do the jumping from planet to planet but I have a small problem on where the players up direction is facing.

While landing somewhere in the middle of the planet the player changes his up direction in the opposite way he was facing when he first made the jump, if he lands somewhere close to the edge my logic fails.

As you can see in the photo bellow the Y axis is facing the wrong direction and it should face in the direction where the X axis is facing right now.

What would be the right logic to follow for the player Y axis to face the correct way?

[image]

// Jump from a planet

```
void Update()
{
    if (TouchListener.Instance.Tap)
    {
        isOrbiting = false;
        _rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

// Rotating around the planet

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    
    if (planet != null && isOrbiting)
        transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.localPosition, transform.forward * -1, orbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

// Handling the player entering the orbit. Here's where I inverse the up direction of the player. Also stopping any kind of force or rotation

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Planet"))
    {
        if (!isOrbiting)
            score++;
        planet = other.gameObject;
        isOrbiting = true;
        if (score > 0)
        {
            _rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            _rb.angularVelocity = 0f;
            _rb.rotation = 0f;
            transform.up = transform.up * -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to set the player's up to be facing away from the planet and its forward to be world forward (away from camera):

```
static void SetPlayerUp(Transform player, Transform planet)
{
    player.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, 
            player.position - planet.position);
}
```

Consider calling this instead of `_rb.rotation = 0f;` and `transform.up = transform.up * -1;`